# google custom search getting no results

Tags: search, tabs, spry

I made a Google custom search for my site and I can't seem to get it to work. Every time I try to use it, it gives me 'no results'. I tried the forum on the Google site but no one responded. So if any of you have an idea why it's not working that would be great!

Here's the code:

```
    <div class="searchbox" id="searchbox"><script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '014409856576262012500:d5cgsozp8m0';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript';     gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse,     s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
</div>
```

My site mainly consists of Spry Tabbed Panels, but I thought the search box should work with that.

Here's the site:
http://emilymagnuson.com/trustbank/index.html

Thank you!